# Как правильно работать с timestamp в laravel5?

Tags: php, laravel, carbon

Делаю комментарии. В модели Comment помимо стандартной даты created_at есть еще дата родителя created_at_parent.

По умолчанию created_at_parent == created_at.

Создаю объект Comment, присваиваю $comment->created_at к $comment->created_at_parent и после сохранения получаю даты с разницой 3 часа.

```
$comment = new Comment();
$comment->text = $request->get('text');
$comment->created_at_parent = $comment->created_at;
$comment->save();
```

Если делать предварительный parse через carbon то все ок

```
   $comment = new Comment();
   $comment->text = $request->get('text');
   $comment->created_at_parent = Carbon::parse($comment->created_at);
   $comment->save();
```

p.s. Я добавлял в модель Comment, protected $dates = ['created_at_parent'];
Не помогло.

Как правильно работать с датой в таком случае?

Comment: Это влияние временной зоны. Можете показать, как именно выглядит `created_at`?

Comment: Это понятно. выглядит так - http://rghost.ru/6BJxk8VHp/image.png

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том что $comment->created_at пустой до вызова метода save();

```
$comment = new Comment();
$comment->text = $request->get('text');
$comment->created_at = Carbon::now();
$comment->created_at_parent = $comment->created_at;
$comment->save();
```